# Execute only selected jobs using Jenkins pipe line

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have this jenkins pipe line which has multiple stages. Inside these stages, there are multiple jobs being executed.
When I build the job I'd like to have a set of check boxes and the pipe line should build only what I've checked inside the pipeline stages. Is there any plugins or methods I can use to achieve this?

Sample pipeline code.

As per below example, there are jobs called job_A1, job_B1, job_C1, job_D1, job_A2, job_B2, job_C2 and job_D2. If I click Build with parameters, it should prompt me check boxes and I should be able to check any job I want so that the pipe line will build only the ones I checked.

### Thanks in Advance.

```
pipeline {
  agent {label 'server01'}
  stages {
    stage('Build 01') {
      steps {

        parallel (
                    "BUILD A1" : {
                        build job: 'job_A1',
                            parameters:[
                                string(name: 'PARAM01', value: "$PARAM01"),
                                string(name: 'PARAM02', value: "$PARAM02")
                                ]
                        },
                    "BUILD B1" : {
                        build job: 'job_B1',
                            parameters:[
                                string(name: 'PARAM01', value: "$PARAM01"),
                                string(name: 'PARAM02', value: "$PARAM02")
                                ]
                        },
                    "BUILD C1" : {
                        build job: 'job_C1',
                            parameters:[
                                string(name: 'PARAM01', value: "$PARAM01"),
                                string(name: 'PARAM02', value: "$PARAM02")
                                ]
                        },
                    "BUILD D1" : {
                        build job: 'job_D1',
                            parameters:[
                                string(name: 'PARAM01', value: "$PARAM01"),
                                string(name: 'PARAM02', value: "$PARAM02")
                                ]
                        },
            )
        }
    }

    stage('Build 02') {
      steps {

        parallel (
                    "BUILD A2" : {
                        build job: 'job_A2',
                            parameters:[
                                string(name: 'PARAM01', value: "$PARAM01"),
                                string(name: 'PARAM02', value: "$PARAM02")
                                ]
                        },
                    "BUILD B2" : {
                        build job: 'job_B2',
                            parameters:[
                                string(name: 'PARAM01', value: "$PARAM01"),
                                string(name: 'PARAM02', value: "$PARAM02")
                                ]
                        },
                    "BUILD C2" : {
                        build job: 'job_C2',
                            parameters:[
                                string(name: 'PARAM01', value: "$PARAM01"),
                                string(name: 'PARAM02', value: "$PARAM02")
                                ]
                        },
                    "BUILD D2" : {
                        build job: 'job_D2',
                            parameters:[
                                string(name: 'PARAM01', value: "$PARAM01"),
                                string(name: 'PARAM02', value: "$PARAM02")
                                ]
                        },
            )
        }
    }

      }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @mbn217  for your answer, but ExtendedChoice parameter didn't help much in my scenario.
Anyway, I could do it using boolean parameters and calling it inside the pipeline using the script tag.

***Example pipeline script***

```
stage ('BUILD A') {
            steps {
                script {
                if (params.get('boolA',true)) {
                build job: '_build_A', parameters:  [string(name: 'param1', value: "$param1"),string(name: 'param2', value: "$param2")]
            }   else {
                echo "A is not selected to build"
                }
                }

            }   
        }

        stage ('BUILD B') {
            steps {
                script {
                if (params.get('boolB',true)) {
                build job: '_build_B', parameters:  [string(name: 'param1', value: "$param1"),string(name: 'param2', value: "$param2")]
            }   else {
                echo "B is not selected to build"
                }
                }

            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExtendedChoiceParameter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) to accomplish what you want. Basically you will nee to parametrize job Names too using this jenkins plugin.
You can use a list of checkboxes as shown in the screen shot 
[image: screenshot]